# how to handle ORA-00942 error in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Generally in plain jdbc ,   we handle the `ORA-00942 table or view does not exist`  error  using try catch block like below

```
try{
     //this code throws ORA-90042
    }catch(Exception ex){
         //  check if it's ORA-90042
    }
```

What should be the approach in spring jdbctemplate with  ORA-00942 table or view does not exist error?

Should I handle in the same way  using try catch block  or is there any better way. ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the table or view does not exist? How do you want to handle it? Spring-JDBCTemplate does not have database vendor specific exception handling written into it. It's database agnostic.

Comment: I just want to ignore that specific exception and let the program flow continue. and maybe print just a one liner in the log saying "ORA-00942 occurred".

Comment: basically my question is simple..  how do i catch ORA-00942 exceptions in spring jdbctemplate?

Comment: I am not sure if plain exceptions are tranlated and wrapped by spring jdbc template as in spring jpa. But just make a simple test case to provoke the exception. Your test will fail or you see it in console log and just catch this exception.

Comment: The exceptio will be wrapped. You will see an example of the very same exception here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495461/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-with-spring-jdbc-template-in-spring-boot
If you are asking if Sping has some Springy way of handling DB specific exceptions, then no.